# How to tell when calculating an Intercept Point between two moving objects, when it will never intercept?

Tags: vector, lua, simulation, linear-algebra, traffic-simulation

I'm not a maths person and the formulas you see on maths type questions/answer with all the symbols is completely beyond me - I'm sorry. However I had help about 18 months ago to turn a provided formula into lua script to make the calculation for two aircraft to intercept each other. I will admit, I don't know why that formula works, and I wouldn't know how to change it to make it do other things; I need to get this working for a flight sim project, but learning all the maths for this one problem would take too long and I have no-one who could teach me. (I don't learn well from books). Please be understanding and not too critical of my lack of maths skills.

The premise is one aircraft will maintain it's course (target) and the other (interceptor) will alter it's course to intercept with the target aircraft at some point in the future.

The formula/code I made for that is this in lua below (It was based on a simulation page tutorial on calculating lead shots for firing a bullet in an FPS and where it will hit a moving target - obviously that works in an FPS as you intend to only shoot when pointing at a target, but here there is a change of asking for an intercept that can never happen):

```
    -- Point intercept(Point const &shooter, double bullet_speed, Point const &target, Vector const &target_velocity)
    -- {
    --     double a = bullet_speed*bullet_speed - target_velocity.dot(target_velocity);
    --     double b = -2*target_velocity.dot(target-shooter);
    --     double c = -(target-shooter).dot(target-shooter);

    --     return target+largest_root_of_quadratic_equation(a,b,c)*target_velocity;
    -- }

  local targetMINUSInterceptor   = TVF.VecSubtract(interceptorVec3Point, targetVec3Point)
  local targetVelocityDotProduct = TVF.VecDot(targetVelocityAsVec3, targetVelocityAsVec3)

  local a = interceptorSpeedAsNumber * interceptorSpeedAsNumber - targetVelocityDotProduct
  local b = -2 * TVF.VecDot(targetVelocityAsVec3, targetMINUSInterceptor)
  local c = -TVF.VecDot(targetMINUSInterceptor, targetMINUSInterceptor)

  local result = TVF.VecAdd(targetVec3Point, (TVF.MultiplyVectorByNumber(targetVelocityAsVec3, TVF.GetLargestRootOfQuadraticEquation(a,b,c))))
```

Now, that all works perfectly, but only IF both aircraft are travelling in directions and speeds that CAN intercept (even with required turns for the Interceptor).

However, if you have, for example, the target aircraft heading West, and East of that target you have the Interceptor aircraft heading East (i.e. moving away from each other and already are tail to tail to each other), and allowing for the fact that the interceptor can't go fast enough to catch up and overtake the target aircraft, then the above calculation/formula still gives a position vector, however it's either 'off the map' or in some weird direction and massive magnitude that makes no practical sense.

I need to know when this calculation (or a modified version of it) gives a possible interception point, and also when it can't give an interception point. This will allow me to make a branching decision in my code to warn the players when an interception is not possible and the target aircraft would have to change it's direction and/or speed and try again.

Could someone please help? My maths level is very basic trig, so I'd really appreciate it if you could spell it out for me or give me the corrected formula with explanations words for all the terms please.

Comment: Check out pages 993-994 of [this paper](https://www.informs-sim.org/wsc05papers/118.pdf) from the proceedings of the 2005 Winter Simulatiton Conference. (And no, we don’t simulate winter at that conference, that’s when the conference is held each year.)

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I'm not sure how that helps, and remember when I said I didn't understand all those mathematical symbols and formal formulas? Well that paper is full of them... so it's not really of any help at all.

Comment: Since you have neither specified a language nor given a minimal reproducible example, the only other option I see for describing a solution is to express it with math. The linked paper shows that there's an algebraic solution based on the [quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula), and provides it.

Comment: I'm sure I said Lua... and reproducible example?! I've posted the original code (in commented form) and the lua code I made from that formula to do the calculation.

I haven't repeated the standard vector maths formulas because those are just that - standard!